# Showing $\frac{1}{x^3+x}$ is continuous at $x=1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I've been attempting to use the definition of continuity and felt a little uncertain about my working on this question.

We define $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta $ s.t .....

Let $\lvert x-1\rvert < 1 $:

$\lvert \frac{1}{x^3+x}-\frac{1}{2} \rvert = \lvert \frac{2-x^3-x}{2x^3+2x}\rvert = \lvert (x-1)\rvert\lvert\frac{-x^2-x-2}{2x^3+2x}\rvert$

Then we restrict $\delta < 1$ so now $ 0<x<2$ which tells us that

$\lvert\frac{-x^2-x-2}{2x^3+2x}\rvert<-\frac{2}{5}$

Hence $\lvert (x-1)\rvert\lvert\frac{-x^2-x-2}{2x^3+2x}\rvert < -\frac{2\delta}{5}<\epsilon$.

So we must choose $\delta > -\frac{2\epsilon}{5}$.

However I am used to finding something of the form $0<\delta<$min{$a,b$}

Does this mean the solution is  $-\frac{2\epsilon}{5}<\delta<1$ ?

Apologies if this is really trivial/simple, I have just never seen a solution like that so wondered if perhaps I made an error somewhere.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your "which tells us"?

Comment: Which tells us that the absolute value is less then the *negative*??? There is no bound on the LHS if $x$ can approach $0$ because it makes the LHS become infinity.

Comment: Hmm.. I see it is incorrect now. Since there was a restriction on x now, I just subbed in the maximum x value which gives $-\frac{2}{5}$ and assumed it was also the maximum value of that function which of course not true.. does this make it the minimum then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\left|\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}-\frac12\right|=\left|\frac{x^2+x+2}{2x(x^2+1)}\right|\,|x-1|$$

Now, we need to bound $x$ away from $0$.  So, let us first restrict $x$ so that $1/2<x<3/2$.  Then, we see that

$$\left|\frac{x^2+x+2}{2x(x^2+1)}\right|\le \frac{(3/2)^2+(3/2)+2}{((1/2)^2+1)}=\frac{23}{5}$$

Hence, we see that

$$\left|\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}-\frac12\right|\le \frac{23}5|x-1|<\epsilon$$

whenever $|x-1|<\delta=\min\left(1/2,\frac{5}{23}\epsilon\right)$.

Comment: Could you explain why you picked that specific restriction on x?

Comment: We needed to bound $x$ away from $0$.  So, we arbitrarily chose $|x-1|<1/2$.  We could have chosen any number $0<r<1$ and restricted $x$ so that $|x-1|<r$.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I've seen this done a few times and still wonder why. You took out a factor of $-1$ when you did the subtraction early on right?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And yes, $|-1|=1$.

Comment: Apologies for all the questions I'm just really struggling to get used to this method. Should it not a $+2$ in that case? As initially the numerator (with the factor of $-1$ still applied) would be $-x^2-x-2$ ?

Comment: You're right;  I've edited.

Comment: Perfect it makes much more sense now! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Pleased to hear!  And you are quite welcome. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

I like to my limits
go to zero,
so,
let $x = 1+y$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\lvert \frac{1}{x^3+x}-\frac{1}{2} \rvert
&=\lvert \frac{1}{(1+y)^3+(1+y)}-\frac{1}{2} \rvert\\
&=\lvert \frac{1}{y^3+3y^2+4y+2}-\frac{1}{2} \rvert\\
&=\lvert \frac{2-(y^3+3y^2+4y+2)}{2(y^3+3y^2+4y+2)}\rvert\\
&=\lvert \frac{-(y^3+3y^2+4y)}{2(y^3+3y^2+4y+2)}\rvert\\
&=\lvert \frac{-y(y^2+3y+4)}{2(y^3+3y^2+4y+2)}\rvert\\
\end{array}
$

As $y \to 0$,
$\frac{(y^2+3y+4)}{2(y^3+3y^2+4y+2)}
\to 1
$,
so
$\frac{-y(y^2+3y+4)}{2(y^3+3y^2+4y+2)}
\to 0$.